# Selenium request returns error 400 - Bad request

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, puppeteer, http-status-code-400

I'm trying to get pull data from http://43.248.49.97/indexEn

Normally on the browser there is a first request to the url above returns error 412, the second one is to a JS file and the third one is also to the url above and returns ok (200).

When using selenium the third request returns error 400 - Bad request instead.

I'm using Python. Any ideas on why this is happening?]

Thanks

Comment: How do you get code-response with selenium?

Comment: I manually open the console, go to Network and check Preserve log before commanding to go to the site

Comment: My understanding is the JS script returned is testing if you are using selenium and blocking it on purpose. I tried some workarounds that we find on the net (like modifying the webdriver binary) without success. I also tried to read the JS script... but it seems just random. If you discover a way to bypass this issue and continue scraping it, please share :-)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with you but I found a solution which perfectly solves my problem.

Maybe your program fails because you are detected as a robot using selenium.
So here is the method to solve it or hide your identity(window.navigator.webdriver) by using JavaScript:

With CDP(Chrome Devtools-Protocol), you run the code before the frame is loaded by the JS file(detector). Therefore, use these codes to remove the "webdriver True" property:

```
Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
      get: () => undefined
    })
```

key codes:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
driver = Chrome('D://chromedriver.exe')
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
  "source": """
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
      get: () => undefined
    })
  """
})
driver.get('http://pythonlearner.com')
```

However, if you upgrade your Chrome to 88 right now. The method mentioned above will be useless. Fortunately, we still have a solution (add this code)

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
```

These codes should help you pass the JS file so that you can obtain the data. At least I successfully run my program.

Answer (score 1):

I am using ChromeDriver 104.0.5112.79.0 and the solution with chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled") works for me!