# 400 Bad Request R Selenium

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

Each time I navigate to a specific website using RSelenium, I get 400 Bad request. Other websites work fine, eg google.

```
fprof <- makeFirefoxProfile(list(general.useragent.override=sample(user_agent_list,1)))
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, extraCapabilities = fprof )

remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://www.google.com")
```

The website is written correctly, is there anything else I can do to overcome this error?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62267642/selenium-request-returns-error-400-bad-request) you can find a related question.

Comment: unfortunately I'm not sure how to translate this question to RSelenium