# Scraping a dynamic table in an iframe

Tags: python, database, web-scraping

I am accessing a website that provides statistics (a government website in China, free for use). I have to make two clicks to select what I want, solve a captcha, and get a table of 300K rows in an iFrame, display 200 rows per page, and I want to download all the data.

There is a download option but it exports a CSV file with 10K records only.

Any suggestions? I do all my code in Python.
The source of data is here: http://43.248.49.97/indexEn (Chinese customs)

Comment: What have you tried? What is the specific obstacle you're coming across? You should probably also note that if they have a captcha they're unlikely to be ok with scrapers taking data.

Comment: I looked in the debugger to see if I can see the source of data, the website is pause in the debugger mode so I can't see anything. In term of data, I can get them all in two hours manually by making smaller request, but it would be nice to be able to do it automatically in one click!

Comment: Please, see the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62267642/selenium-request-returns-error-400-bad-request